# Laravel validation

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I have problem with Laravel validation when validation fails it also call block of code where it should be successful...

I am trying to check for some user id if his admin_id field equal with user which is currently logged.

Here is code:

```
$auth = Auth::user()->id;
$inputs = array(
    'id' => Input::get('id')
);

$rules = array(
    'id' => "required|exists:users,id,admin_id,$auth"
);

$validate = Validator::make($inputs, $rules);

if ($validate->fails()) {
    return $validate->messages()->all();
} else {
    return 'succes';
}
```

Comment: Can you check with a static `admin_id`? Like `"required|exists:users,id,admin_id,1"`

Comment: It was problem with testing trought Chrome.Code above works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

```
$rules = array(
  'id' => "required|exists:users,id,admin_id," . $auth
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without validation.

```
$auth = Auth::user()->id;
$input = Input::get('id');

if($auth != $input){
    return 'your custom error message';
}else{
    return 'success';
}
```